How to fix Winforms image problem System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException?
Always when i run this error occurs

System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "CppCLRWinFormsProject.Form1.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "CppCLR_WinFormsProject1" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'

And when i remove the image the code work properly can any one help me ?
this->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.BackgroundImage")));


The code you posted is not standard C++.  The Image^ is a syntax error in C++.  Maybe you want C# or C++/CLI.  Have you tried accessing BackgroundImage without the this-> syntax?

I recommend creating an [mcve] and pasting the code in plaintext.  This would help us debug and understand your code.
